# PowerShell create file for each distinct record

Tags: powershell

Working with large CSV file as shown below... 
Need to loop and create file for each distince AppID
i.e below would have three files for AppID 1,3 and 5.
Any help to do this with powershell would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
Col1   | AppID
data11 | 1
data12 | 1
data13 | 1
data31 | 3
data32 | 3
data51 | 5
data52 | 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the bar as a delimiter, then this should work:

```
import-csv .\foo.csv -Delimiter '|' | group-object appid | foreach-object {
    $_.group | Export-Csv "appid_$($_.name).csv" -NoTypeInformation }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. I just tried this on the sample file and it works like a charm!

Comment: I'm just getting one file.

Comment: Using the data you provided, my answer is correct. If you are using different data, clearly there are no guarantees. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Ok, you marked it correct - I'm guessing you were hung up on the delimiter. Is your CSV file really using a bar character was it actually a comma? :)

Comment: yep, delimiter was the issue. Thanks for your help..
and you'll be getting lots more question :)